# What is the best paper-based dictionary?

Tags: dictionaries

I'd like to have a dictionary in paper that won't be very big, at least there should be one tome, and it should be something like thefreedictionary.com but in paper, to use it offline.
Please advise.

Comment: If English is your second language, the best dictionary is the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English (5th edition).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For American English, at least, you can't go wrong with either of these:

[Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026IBXXM)

[American Heritage Collegiate Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CB064G)

For British English, I recommend:

[Concise Oxford English Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199548412)

Answer (score 3):

I like the advanced learner's dictionaries. For British English, they are

*Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary*

*Collin's Cobuild Advanced Dictionary*

*Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary*

*Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*

*Macmillan Dictionary for Advanced Learners*

For American English, they are

*Merriam-Webster's Advanced Learner's English Dictionary*

*Oxford Advanced American Dictionary*

They may not contain etymologies or as many words as the bigger dictionaries but have definitions and example sentences that are very helpful to both native speakers and advanced learners alike.

Answer (score 3):

I really like the *Collins English Dictionary*. Also very good (it is particularly well laid out) is the *Oxford Dictionary of English*. Both of these dictionaries contain much encyclopedic material. The *Oxford* really doubles as an encyclopedia and its American English counterpart is the *New Oxford American Dictionary*.

Answer (score 2):

The *OED* is widely regarded as the best English dictionary but the full dictionary is about 27 volumes and requires several shelves. There is also a single-volume microprint version that comes with chunky magnifying glass. But it's still much bigger than a regular "desk dictionary". New editions are released very infrequently.

Then there is the *Shorter Oxford Dictionary* which is sometimes published as a single volume and sometimes as a two volume set. New editions are more frequent than for the full OED.

Also excellent is *Webster's Third New International*. New editions no longer seem to be published.

The OED focuses on British English and Websters focuses on American English but both deal with all varieties.

Oxford also publishes many other dictionaries out of Britain and America.

The name "Websters" is not trademarked so unfortunately besides the many other genuine Websters dictionaries you will also find many inferior ones using the Webster name as a free ride.

Other good desk dictionaries of English are published by *Collins* regularly and in Australia *The MacQuarie Dictionary* is the most highly regarded.